# Do the chefs need to be present when Eiruv Tavshilin is done?

Tags: cooking-bishul, motzi-yedei-chovato, eruv-tavshilin

Do all those who will be cooking in the house need to be present when the Eruv Tavshilin is made, or can one person per household make it, and everyone else benefit from it?

Comment: @msh210, I don't know if "shome'a ke'oneh" really applies here; they in fact don't have to be in earshot when the eiruv is made.

Comment: @Alex, but the question was whether they need to be. Anyway, better now?

Comment: @msh, yep, looks good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latter. This is based on the principle that זכין לאדם שלא בפניו - you can confer a benefit on someone without their being present. You just have to inform them, before they start doing things on Yom Tov to prepare for Shabbos, that it was done.

(Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 527:9)

Comment: Do you *have* to tell them for it to work, or would they just be silly to do so without knowing?